# JMockit mock overridden method

Tags: jmockit

```
Class A 
{ 
   doThis(//expensive stuff)
}

Class B extends A 
{ 
   doThis( super.doThis(); // more expensive stuff )
}
```

I want to mock out the super class doThis but drawing a blank. I don't want to test the super class functionality as I've already done that in isolation, and it's a pain to stage.

Closest I can get is to use

```
new MockUp<B> {
  doThis()
}
```

If I then create a new B it will correctly mock doThis. But if I create a new A the mock isn't honoured and the the real B.doThis is called.

Is there a better way to do what I want with JMockit?

Thanks

Comment: This is how you do it

Comment: according to the question, if you have already tested class A, then why are you calling it again?

Comment: It should be `MockUp<A>`, not `MockUp<B>`, if the intent is to mock the super class `A`.